# Laplacian mapping on various function spaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, ap.analysis-of-pdes

I have a question related to a certain elliptic operator on $R^N$ but I think i can clarify my confusion if I just consider the Laplacian $\Delta$ on the unit ball in $R^N$.

If $ 1 <p< \infty$ we know that $ \Delta:W_0^{2,p}(B) \rightarrow L^p(B)$ is an isomorphism (one to one, onto, continuous, inverse continous).   Here I am using some non standard notation in the sense that by $W^{2,p}_0(B)$ i mean the functions in $W^{2,p}(B)$ which are zero on the boundary.    Now we know the above does not hold for $p=1,\infty$.

I am interested in having the target space to be $L^\infty(B)$.   So, as well known counterexamples show,  there are examples of $ f $ bounded such that the solution $ \Delta u =f $ in $B$ with $u=0$ are not in $W^{2,\infty}$.  So the inverse isn't continuous.

So I would like to just try and define the appropriate space on the left using some graph norm type idea.    So , for instance,  pick $ N<p< \infty$ and set 
$$ X:=\{ u \in W^{2,p}_0(B):   \Delta u \in L^\infty\} $$  and lets put the norm

$ \| u\| = \| \Delta u \|_{L^\infty} $.

So it appears $X$ is a Banach space and $ \Delta :X \rightarrow L^\infty$  should be an isomorpism.  Is this correct?

If this is the case I realize that $X$ is slightly bigger than $ W^{2,\infty}_0$  (as defined above).

My functional analysis has decayed to zero and so any comments would be greatly appreciated.

thanks
Craig

Comment: As a slightly off-topic comment, if you are interested in the Laplacian in $W^{k,p}$, are you aware of the concept of [$p$-Laplacian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-Laplacian)? It has also been [studied for $p=\infty$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinity_Laplacian).

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I am not interested in this case you mentioned directly,  but maybe it would help clarify my situation.  I will attempt to google it.  Thanks.

Comment: In addition to googling it, you can use the links in my comment. Unfortunately links in comments are next to invisible here. There is a link to Lindqvist's notes in the first Wikipedia article, and that might be a good introduction to the topic if Wikipedia seems insufficient.

Comment: I will take a look at links and notes you recommended (and your right,  i hadn't scene the link).    Thanks

Comment: You write that $\Delta(W^{2,p}_0)=L^p(B)$, which contains $L^{\infty}$, so $X$ is indeed (by definition) isomorphic to this space. I don't see any relation whatsoever of your question to $p$-Laplacians other than the fact that the letter $p$ is used both times.